# Hibernate annotation onDelete not handed in shema export

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, persistence

I have a problem with hibernate 4.3.5 annotations. 
I have a project where I use annotations and hibernate shema export to generate my database. All the JPAs annotation works fine and the database is well generated.
The problem comes when I want to add an hibernate annotation : onDelete. This annotation is ignored by the shema export and I can't find a way to make it work.
I have searched a lot and found some similar topics but none of them solved my problem.

```
@Entity
@Table (name="comment")
public class Comment{
    ...
    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OnDelete (action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name="from_user_id_comment")
    User fromUser;
    ...
}
```

My relation is bidirectionnal. (I have a list of comments in the class User).

The SQL script generated for the creation of the table "comment" is the following :

```
Hibernate: 
    create table comment (
        ...
        from_user_id_comment integer,
        ...
        primary key (id_comment)
    )


Hibernate: 
    alter table comment 
        add constraint FK_7m60iklffdi8xx9m6tw8ci4w7 
        foreign key (from_user_id_comment) 
        references user (id_user)
```

I use maven to handle my dependencies.

What I want hibernate to do is to generate the "ON DELETE CASCADE" with the constraint, so th cascade is handled by the DB.

Can somebody help me please ?

Thanks,

Pat

**pom.xml dependencies :**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Hibernate schema export does not generate SQL CASCADE DELETE for JPA cascades.

Comment: Is there a way to do it ? I mean not manually

Comment: You would need to customize the schema export. AFAIK this is not easy and I would not do it just for sake of one project. I am also not sure I would want translate JPA cascades into SQL cascades on my projects. Btw the cascade might be specified on the ManyToOne, you do not need the OnDelete annotation.

Comment: I just managed to make it work. Schema export can generate SQL CASCADE DELETES, but not with the simple MySQLDialect. I have no idea why. It generates them with other dialects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work.

The hibernate MySQLdialect (and MySQL5Dialect as well) doesn't translate @OnDelete annotations into "ON DELETE CASCADE" statements. I have no idea why.

My database is a MySQL5 DB with an InnoDB engine.
I found out that I could use the MySQL5InnoDBDialect, and it worked !

The only change I made was in my hibernate.cfg.xml file, at the line :

```
<property name="dialect">
    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
</property>
```

Now the schema export generates **ON DELETE CASCADE** statements for my **@OnDelete (action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)** annotations

```
Hibernate: 
    alter table comment 
        add constraint FK_7m60iklffdi8xx9m6tw8ci4w7 
        foreign key (from_user_id_comment) 
        references user (id_user)
        on delete cascade
```

For other dialects supported by Hibernate , see this page : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html